# Dart HashMap initial value

Tags: dart

I have a `final HashMap` in a class, How can I have a default value for it?

```
class RoomsState {
  final HashMap<int, int> myMap;

  RoomsState({
    this.myMap= const {}
  });

}
```

as `const {}` is a `Map` and not `HashMap` I cannot do it, Also `HashMap` is not a const constructor

Comment: The map literal type 'Map<int, int>' isn't of expected type 'HashMap<int, int>'. The maps's type can be changed with an explicit generic type arguments or by changing the key and value types.

Comment: I wouldn't use `HashMap<int, int>` as type for the variable. Just use `Map<int, int>`. I wouldn't even bother making a distinction between `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` unless I can see the performance difference (which you can't on the VM, it's the same code).
So `final Map<int, int> myMap; RoomState({Map<int, int>? myMap}) : myMap = myMap ?? createDefaultMap(); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could expect a Map in your constructor and then convert it to a HashMap in an initializer.

```dart
class RoomsState {
  final HashMap<int, int> myMap;

  RoomsState({
    Map<int, int> map = const {},
  }) : myMap = HashMap.from(map);
}
```

Comment: You generally should prefer using `HashMap.of` over `HashMap.from`. `.from` is meant to be used when you need to cast the elements to a different type.

Comment: thanks for that hint @jamesdlin. Can you guide me to the corresponding docs, so I can include them in the answer?

Comment: It's alluded to in https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-listfrom-unless-you-intend-to-change-the-type-of-the-result (which talks about `List.from`, but it also applies to `Set.from`, `Map.from`, etc.).  It's also evident (but not obvious) from the signatures of `.from()` vs `.of()`; `.from()` constructors usually use `dynamic` type parameters.  Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/2066

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the only way to do it, but it is an option:

```
import 'dart:collection';

class RoomsState {
  final HashMap<int, int> myMap;

  RoomsState({
    HashMap<int, int>? myMap
  }) : this.myMap = myMap ?? HashMap();
}
```

The `myMap` parameter are here nullable since we are using the `null` value to identify if we got any argument.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` has the construtor `of`  that creates a `HashMap` that contains all key/value pairs of other. Check [this](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.2/dart-collection/HashMap/HashMap.of.html) for reference.

Example:

```
HashMap<String, String> englishToFrench = HashMap.of({
  "go": "aller",
  "buy": "acheter",
  "sleep": "dormir",
});
```

Usage example:

```
void main() {
  print(englishToFrench["go"]);
}
```

Output:

```
aller
```